# Joseph Rotman, "Theory of Groups," Permutation Notation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation

In the proof of Lemma 1.4 (page 8), J. Rotman's "Introduction to the Theory of Groups," there are 2 $\mapsto$ symbols in the permutation notation.

$c_i \mapsto c_{i+1} \mapsto c_{i+1}$.

Why 2? What does the 2nd $\mapsto$ mean?

Comment: There ought to be an explanation of the notation in the book.

Comment: $a\mapsto b$ means $a$ is sent to, or mapped to, $b$ by the function in question.

Answer (score 1):

He's looking at a composition of two permutations (cycles, specifically), and when he writes an expression of the form $x \mapsto y \mapsto z$, he means that the first permutation sends $x$ to $y$, and then the second permutation sends $y$ to $z$, so that the effect of the composition as a whole is $x \mapsto z$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input!

In the proof of Lemma 1.4, there is a **product** of 2 cycles on the left and right hand sides.  This was overlooked.  Viz.,

$(a \: b)(a \: c_1 \dots c_k \: b \: d_1 \dots d_l) = (a \: c_1 \dots c_k)(b \: d_1 \dots d_l)$.

So, let $\beta = (a \: b)$, and $\alpha = $ the right-hand cycle on the LHS.  Then computing, e.g.,

$\beta \alpha(a) = \beta(\alpha(a)) = \beta(c_1) = c_1$,

$\beta \alpha(c_i) = \beta(\alpha(c_i)) = \beta(c_{i+1}) = c_{i+1}$, etc.

So, the $\beta = (a \: b)$ transposition on the left acts only on the $c_i$ or $d_j$ in $\alpha$ adjacent to $a$ or $b$.  Otherwise, it's a shift to the right for the other $c_i$ or $d_j$